# Android gradle issue with sdk versions

Tags: android, gradle, sdk

I had an error being returned after doing Build for the emulator even though none was shown when doing Rebuild. After some online research I discovered that the reason for that might be compileSdkVersion and buildToolsVersion not matching or compileSdkVersion  not being supported by targetSdkVersion. Unfortunately changing the compileSdkVersion to 18 doesn't help but rather returns a huge number of errors. Does anyone have any idea how to resolve this?

compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
...
minSdkVersion 18
targetSdkVersion 24
...
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'

Comment: You might get a better and quicker answer if you included your error from the build.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using buildToolsVersion '25.0.0', you habe to use compileSdkVersion 25

If you are using compileSdkVersion 24, you have to use something like buildToolsVersion 24.0.3

Comment: If I use buildToolsVersion 24 that should still work for a device with API 18, right?

Comment: Yes, if your minSdkVersion is lower than 18 or equals 18

Comment: it still returns an error :
Error:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output.